# Which element is A?

Tags: physical-chemistry, elements

Which element used to be represented by the letter A? I'm guessing sulfur but this is only a guess. It's mentioned in Gamow (1930), "Mass Defect Curve and Nuclear Constitution". Proceedings of the Royal Society A. 126 (803): 632.

Comment: Are you referring to the phrase ‘nucleus “A”’ on page 640?

Comment: No. Page 632, footnote. $A_{32}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon):

> Until 1957, the symbol for argon was "A", but now it is "Ar".

[This table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_nuclides#Full_table) of nuclides lists ${}^{32}$Ar.